# How do I detect mouse-position in a menu bar app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to develop a mac program using Xcode and cocoa. Im tying to make a menubar application in which you press a shortcut key and it will detect your mouse position on the screen. Is it possible to do this if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for obtaining the mouse position in the screen simply use:

```
    NSPoint point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
```

As for the shortcuts well they only work if you are currently have the menubar menu open. If you want to be able to use the shortcut anywhere (whether the menubar is selected or not) use a global hotkey manager. I suggest DDHotkey which you can obtain from here: 
https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

Source:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html